# How to fix SSL certification error when downloading python 3.9.0 with pyenv on macOS Monterey?

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, pyenv, macos-monterey

sorry for any formatting errors.  Am new to this.  I am currently trying to get into the habit of using pyenv.  I am not able to install 3.9.0 via '''pyenv install 3.9.0'''

I keep getting
BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.4 using python-build 20180424)

Results logged to /var/folders/q6/k3f34wm54ns_n2q_vx0n6xt80000gn/T/python-build.20220714193417.14118.log

Last 10 log lines:
/var/folders/q6/k3f34wm54ns_n2q_vx0n6xt80000gn/T/python-build.20220714193417.14118 ~
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

as the result.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a company network which intercepts traffic, get the public certificate and try setting this env variable first. `export CURL_CA_BUNDLE="/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem`